# C# System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping namespace error

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using win8 and try to write simple ping program in VS 2012.

```
using...
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

...
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("google.com");
var res = pingReply.Address + " " + pingReply.RoundtripTime + " " + pingReply.Status;
```

and recive an error:

**The type or namespace name 'Ping' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.NetworkInformation' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

In **cmd** `dir /b /ad /o-n %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v?.*` give me:

- v4.0.30319
- v3.5
- v3.0
- v2.0.50727
- ...

Also, `System.Net.NetworkInformation` has only *one* Delegate and *two* Classes:

- NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler
- NetworkChange
- NetworkInterface

[img there](http://take.ms/HUme3)

What am I missing? Why only *one* Delegate and *two* Classes?

Comment: Targetting a portable framework maybe? Missing reference to `System.dll` ? Targetting .NET 1.1 or earlier?

Comment: Ran the code, works fine. Just need the System.dll. I am on VS 2012, win 8

Comment: Thanks guys, but I get this [error](https://api.monosnap.com/image/download?id=CTxEq5orLIhPLqsN6h6z1tWuv)

Comment: You've got the wrong Express edition.  This one only lets you create Store apps, no Ping class there.  You'll need the desktop edition.